# is the managed matadata concept for specific site collection, farm or Web application?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata-service

What is the scope of the managed MetaData service?

Is it limited to site collection, Web application or farm?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know about the term set scope, Term set has two scope level Local and Global(read below for more details).

**Term Set**
A Term set is a group of related terms.

Terms sets can have different scope, depending on where you create the term set.

- **Local term sets**    are created within the context of a site
  collection, and are available for use (and visible) only to users of
  that site collection. For example, when you create a term set for a
  metadata column in a list or library, then the term set is local. It
  is available only in the site collection that contains this list or
  library. For example, a media library might have a metadata column
  that shows the kind of media (diagram, photograph, screen shot,
  video, etc.). The list of permitted terms is relevant only to this
  library, and available for use in the library.
- **Global term sets**    are available for use across all sites that
  subscribe to a specific Managed Metadata Service application. For
  example, an organization might create a term set that lists names of
  business units in the organization, such as Human Resources,
  Marketing, Information Technology, and so on.

In addition, you can configure a term set as closed or open. In a closed term set, users can't add new terms unless they have appropriate permissions. In an open term set, users can add new terms in a column that is mapped to the term set.

**Terms**

A term is a specific word or phrase that you associated with an item on a SharePoint site. It is a single item in a term set. A term has a unique ID and it can have many text labels (synonyms). If you work on a multilingual site, the term can have labels in different languages.

**There are two types of terms:**

- **Managed terms**    Managed terms are terms that are pre-defined. Term
  Store administrators organize managed terms into a hierarchical term
  set.
- **Enterprise keywords**    An enterprise keyword is a word or phrase that
  a user adds to items on a SharePoint site. The collection of
  enterprise keywords is known as the Keywords set. Typically, users
  can typically add any word or phrase to an item as a keyword. This
  means that you can use enterprise keywords for folksonomy-style
  tagging. Sometimes, Term Store administrators move enterprise
  keywords into a specific managed term set. When they are part of a
  managed term set, keywords become available in the context of that
  term set.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/introduction-to-managed-metadata-HA102832521.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is a farm service that can be used in one or more web applications serving one or more site collections.

Comment: But it is available under site settings. That's site collection scope. Isn't it.

Comment: It's in Site Settings under Site Features as Term Store management.